# Date to Numeral in Macro - VALUE equivalent in Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I was using following formula in excel to generate a field value:

```
=(B2&"_"&E2&"_"&VALUE(N2))
```

Where E2 and B2 are String values and N2 is date in format `mm/dd/yyyy`

Please note: `Datevalue` function was not converting value from date to numeral, so I used `Value` function in above.

I now have a requirement to generate the same value using Macro but I do not find a `VALUE` function to be working in Macro. I tried `DateValue` in Macro as well but it is not converting date to numeral.

I have created following for Macro but stuck to convert date in Numeral like in above.

```
Range("'Tracking Sheet by date'!B" & wlin02).Value & "_" & Range("'Tracking Sheet by date'!E" & wlin02).Value & "_" & Range("'Tracking Sheet by date'!N" & wlin02).Value
```

`wlin02` variable is being used to read the current line.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CLng to convert the date into the number.

```
Range("'Tracking Sheet by date'!B" & wlin02).Value & "_" & Range("'Tracking Sheet by date'!E" & wlin02).Value & "_" & CLng(Range("'Tracking Sheet by date'!N" & wlin02))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved my problem. Just wanter to confirm if CLng in macro and VALUE in cell formula will always give the same result?

Comment: You're welcome! If the date is without the time part, both will give you the same output. But if the date is with a time part, you will need to use CDbl instead of CLng.